# How to pass the data in between activity to fragment using intent in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can store the value in one variable now I want pass that variable into fragment.

With the following code I am able to load fragments.

```
   public class AndroidListFragmentActivity extends Activity {
Fragment2 f2;
public static String itemname;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apetiserfragement);
    itemname=getIntent().getStringExtra("itemname");
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putString("itemname", itemname);
    f2=new Fragment2();
    f2.setArguments(args);

}
}
```

(Here I load fragment using XML page) itemname

The output is split into into 2 windows one for extend for listfragment(for listview). One for fragments

Fragment2.xml

```
    public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
String itemname;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(getArguments().getString("itemname"));

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

  }
```

AndroidListFragmentActivity in this class itemname I want pass Fragment2.class.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please describe what happens when you run your code? Do you get an error? If so, post the logcat? If not how does the behavior differ from what you want?

Comment: Also, please post your XML layouts.

Answer (score 5):

Use the bundle provided in one of the [fragment constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#instantiate%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29), and then you should be able to retrieve the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) by doing `getArguments()` right where you want to in `onCreateView()`

Example:

```
YourFragment.instantiate(context,"fragName",yourBundleWithValue);
```

Then, in your fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getArguments().getStringValue("name"); //Returns your string value

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Done. You need to instantiate your Fragment either using this method, or by providing your own static constructor (although the latter is taboo).

Comment: i stored itemname value in this class AndroidListFragmentActivity .please see mycode change the code according to my code because i am newer of fragments.please help me YourFragment.instantiate(context,"fragName",yourBundleWithValue);
change able line according to my code.

Comment: please see my updated code. i tried according to your told. but it shows an error in this line System.out.println(getArguments().getString("itemname"));
please help me

Comment: The issue is that when creating a Fragment by inflating an XML view hierarchy (to support different screen geometries using [resource qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseOriQuali)), the Antivity or Fragment performing the inflation does not get a chance to pass arguments to the fragment being inflated, and once the inflation has taken place it's too late to call setArguments().

Comment: Note that the OPs code already calls `setArguments()` and `getArguments()`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `FragmentManager` to display your `Fragment`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @infused This is an XY problem. The OP already uses `setArguments()` and `getArguments()`, so the reason he isn't seeing the fragment displayed is because he isn't using `FragmentManager` to display it.