# How to pass data from activity to it's own fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to pass data from an activity to the fragment it manages. 
I have been trying the code below:
**Activity code:**

```
String accountNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("accountNumber").toString();
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("accountNumber", accountNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

**Fragment code inside onCreateView method:**

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null && args.containsKey("accountNumber")) {
            accountNumber = args.getString("accountNumber").toString();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), accountNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
```

The String accountNumber I get with Intent.getExtra is not null, but when I pass it to the fragment accountNumber results to null ...

I also tried with FragmentManager in the activity class like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
        // Or: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager()
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("accountNumber", accountNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass the data in between activity to fragment using intent in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958975/how-to-pass-the-data-in-between-activity-to-fragment-using-intent-in-android)

Comment: Is this a typo? `String accountNumber = accountNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("accountNumber").toString();` I see two `accountNumber` variables.

Comment: Sorry its a mistake. Edited

Comment: i'm stuck with the same problem, did u found the solution, help me out here

Answer (score 0):

Check what kind of "Fragment" did you import in your Activity. You could be importing and instantiating "android.app.Fragment" while expecting the argument to magically show in your "com.my.application.Fragment".

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;